# Неявная привязка модели к роуту (Route Model Binding) в Laravel если на фронтенде слаги а в админке - id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Здравствуйте. В проекте на Laravel планирую использовать неявную привязку модели к роуту ([Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding)) , но возникает проблема, что на самом сайте для пользователей нужно использовать слагы, а в админки сайта - id.

Если я в моделях определю метод getRouteKeyName() для установки ключа 'slug' тогда уже в админпанели не смогу использовать метод find() который будет принимать id:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Есть ли какое то оптимальное решение такой проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никаких проблем не будет. `find()` (*Find a model by its primary key*) всегда ищет объект по первичному ключу. А `getRouteKeyName()` (*Get the route key for the model*) используется роутингом для поиска объекта. То есть, они никак не связаны.

Или вы хотите, чтобы работали урлы и с slug и с id? Думаю, самым простым будет сделать разные маршруты. Вам в любом случае надо будет контролировать права доступа.